# Not able to login with apple id after updating the mac

Tags: macbook-pro, apple-id

After updating the Macbook when I am trying to login with my Apple ID , then I am getting the error , Verification failed Unknown error occurred , Attached screenshot below :[image]

Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks!!

Comment: Earlier, Have you enabled a Mobile account for your account in Macbook?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different!  Is your internet connection working?  Can you use the same credentials to login to icloud.com?

Comment: Yes My internet is working as I have posted this question from the same laptop

Comment: @Piyush: When you upgrade your MBP, was your account enabled as a mobile account ?

Comment: I just started getting the exact same error across all of my devices (MacBook, iPhone, iPad, iMac). They all started prompting for my Apple ID at the same time, and I get the exact same error on each device. I can't log in on icloud.com, either.